# What's adding <style type="text/css">body { display: none !important }</style>

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

**I followed these instructions for my app:**

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme

**My Index** (before build)

```
 <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/app.css -->
  <link href="app.less" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less">
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

**My dist Index** (in text-editor)

```
<html ng-app="myApp"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>Datavalidering</title> <meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"> <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory --> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.2ac5f564.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.d41d8cd9.css"> </head> <body>
```

**Dist index** (browser)

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">@charset "UTF-8";[ng\:cloak],[ng-cloak],[data-ng-cloak],[x-ng-cloak],.ng-cloak,.x-ng-cloak,.ng-hide:not(.ng-hide-animate){display:none !important;}ng\:form{display:block;}.ng-animate-shim{visibility:hidden;}.ng-anchor{position:absolute;}</style>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title> 
<meta name="description" content=""> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.2ac5f564.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.d41d8cd9.css"> 
<style type="text/css">body { display: none !important }</style></head>
<body>
```

**The problem may be in gruntfile.js**

http://plnkr.co/edit/r2hdhWY7olIw0pBHJ4VF?p=preview

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 7):

This happens because of ([less.js](https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/bcc8ced8b0105c44073a823f441d1fb297697f41/lib/less-browser/bootstrap.js#L34)):

```
// Simulate synchronous stylesheet loading by blocking page rendering
if (!options.async)
{
    css = 'body { display: none !important }';
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    style = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';
    if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }

    head.appendChild(style);
}
```

so, all you need to do is add this before less.js

```
<script>
less = {
    async: true
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thansk!
 
So even if I got 

 `<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
     <!-- bower:js -->
 <script src="bower_components/less/dist/less.js"></script>`

I still need 

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.6.1/less.min.js"></script>` How so?

Comment: No, you dont need it, that was just an example to show that less.js include *MUST* come after configuration

Comment: This is a terrible issue.  Who in their right mind would add display none important to body???

Comment: its to "Simulate synchronous stylesheet loading" https://github.com/less/less.js/blob/bcc8ced8b0105c44073a823f441d1fb297697f41/lib/less-browser/bootstrap.js#L34

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Angular, but had a similar problem where this `<style type="text/css">body { display: none !important }</style>` suddenly appears at the end of `head` tag, effectively renders the whole page to not displaying anything.

I found out that the culprit was `less.js`. Simply commenting the line fixes it.

Comment: So you comment:
 **<script src="bower_components/less/dist/less.js"></script>** out?

If I do that I wont be able to use Less..

Thanks!

Comment: well, at least that should give you an idea where to start looking. In my case, it turns out that I didn't need Less so it was an easy solution to take.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and the culprit.

It comes from the "Jetpack".

This image shows the location of the code in WordPress Directory:

[image]